# onclick() fails after changing javascript version

Tags: javascript, jquery

I accidentally changed Javascript version on Webstorm from ECMAScript 6 to flow.

All onclick() functions like the following defined in html and in javascript stopped working.

```
<div class="just-me" onclick="helloworld();">
```

Gives the following error,

> Uncaught ReferenceError: helloWorld is not defined

I tried to use following approaches,

**javascript:**

```
document.getElementbyId('test').addEventListener('click', helloWorld);
```

**jquery:**

```
$("#test").on('click', helloWorld);
```

I tried to use `console.log()` but nothing is printed in console.
Problem isn't solving even after reverting back to ECMA 6.

Edit: `helloWorld()` is defined and in the scope. This issue happened after javascript version was changed to flow everything worked fine before that.

Comment: It is working, your `helloWorld` function is not found

Comment: try out  ```$("#test").on('click', function(){console.log("hello");});```

Comment: @axelaxel Tried that but still won't work.

Comment: look at the comment under the answer

Comment: It's probably a scope issue. I suspect Flow is nesting the function definition inside another function, but it needs to be a global variable.

Comment: Provide a minimal piece of code that reproduce the problem. Any answers to this question will otherwise be wild guesses

Answer (score 1):

The function `helloWorld` should be defined before using it in `addEventListener()` or `on()`.

Comment: yes, you should use ```$(document).ready``` and then define your event listener

Comment: @axelaxel That's only necessary to solve problems where `document.getElementById()` fails, it has nothing to do with the function definition.

Comment: The question has been updated, they're using the `onclick` attribute in the HTML, no `addEventListener()` or `on()`. Those were just the attempts to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Call your function like this.

```
$("#test").click(function() { helloWorld() });
```

You have to call it inside click wrapper.